# Fill Cells with Vlookup Determined By Data Validation List

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that I would like to have auto-populate cells based on a data validation dropdown list; the list has 2 choices in A2:A100, CR or DR.  The text that I am having fill the cells is a Vlookup from another sheet within the workbook.  If the user selects CR or Dr it fills certain cells with vlookup code that will update the status based on the number the user inputs into B2:B100.

I have tried a few different codes and I keep getting the same results.  It will work fine for a few tries, but for some reason ends up breaking.  The issue I end up having is that if I have multiple numbers filling B2:B100, with all different selections (CR or DR) the end up all switching to the same CR/DR status in A1:A100, or the cells in D2:H100 all fill with '#N/A' and I cant get them to update the cells based on the vlookup.

Example [Here](https://github.com/kanoble88/ExcelVba/blob/master/Example.xlsm)

I have tried with macros, and having the vba fill the cells based on the selection and not macros, and it didn't work as either, I ended up just doing what I have here and am getting the same results.

I found the code on a forum and it worked for a bit, but broke once I cleared contents when all of the cells filled up with '#N/A'.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

On Error Resume Next
    Dim C As Long
    Dim K As Long
    Dim R As Long
    Dim S As Long
    Dim E As Long
    Dim I As Long
    Dim T As Long


    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A2:A70")) Is Nothing Then
        SetApplication False
        With Target
            If StrComp(Trim(.Value), "CR", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then

                'For C = Columns("B").Column To Columns("B").Column
                 '   Cells(.Row, C).Value = "CR"
                'Next C
                'For K = Columns("C").Column To Columns("C").Column
                '    Cells(.Row, K).Value = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'IBM Rational ClearQuest Web'!R2C12:R1048576C18,2,FALSE)"
                'Next K
                For R = Columns("D").Column To Columns("D").Column
                    Cells(.Row, R).Value = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'IBM Rational ClearQuest Web'!R2C2:R1048576C8,2,FALSE)"
                Next R
                For S = Columns("E").Column To Columns("E").Column
                    Cells(.Row, S).Value = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'IBM Rational ClearQuest Web'!R2C2:R1048576C10,7,FALSE)"
                Next S
                'For E = Columns("F").Column To Columns("F").Column
                '    Cells(.Row, E).Value = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-4],'IBM Rational ClearQuest Web'!R2C12:R1048576C18,5,FALSE)"
                'Next E
                For I = Columns("G").Column To Columns("G").Column
                    Cells(.Row, I).Value = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-5],'IBM Rational ClearQuest Web'!R2C2:R1048576C10,9,FALSE)"
                Next I
                For T = Columns("H").Column To Columns("H").Column
                    Cells(.Row, T).Value = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-6],'IBM Rational ClearQuest Web'!R2C2:R1048576C8,3,FALSE)"
                Next T

            ElseIf StrComp(Trim(.Value), "DR", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then

                For K = Columns("C").Column To Columns("C").Column
                    Cells(.Row, K).Value = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'IBM Rational ClearQuest Web'!R2C12:R1048576C18,2,FALSE)"
                Next K
                For R = Columns("D").Column To Columns("D").Column
                    Cells(.Row, R).Value = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'IBM Rational ClearQuest Web'!R2C12:R1048576C18,3,FALSE)"
                Next R
                For S = Columns("E").Column To Columns("E").Column
                    Cells(.Row, S).Value = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'IBM Rational ClearQuest Web'!R2C12:R1048576C18,4,FALSE)"
                Next S
                For E = Columns("F").Column To Columns("F").Column
                    Cells(.Row, E).Value = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-4],'IBM Rational ClearQuest Web'!R2C12:R1048576C18,5,FALSE)"
                Next E
                For I = Columns("G").Column To Columns("G").Column
                    Cells(.Row, I).Value = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-5],'IBM Rational ClearQuest Web'!R2C12:R1048576C18,6,FALSE)"
                Next I
                For T = Columns("H").Column To Columns("H").Column
                    Cells(.Row, T).Value = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-6],'IBM Rational ClearQuest Web'!R2C12:R1048576C18,7,FALSE)"
                Next T
            End If
        End With
        SetApplication True
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub SetApplication(ByVal AppMode As Boolean)

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = AppMode
        .ScreenUpdating = AppMode
    End With
End Sub
```

Here is the code I used when attempting to work with macros:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

On Error Resume Next

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:A99")) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Target.Value
        Case "CR": CR
        Case "DR": DR
    End Select
End If
End Sub

Sub CR()
Dim ThisRow As Long
ThisRow = ActiveCell.Row
Cells(ThisRow, "F").ClearContents
Cells(ThisRow, "G").ClearContents
Cells(ThisRow, "H").ClearContents
Cells(ThisRow, "D").Value = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'IBM Rational ClearQuest Web'!R2C2:R1048576C8,2,FALSE)"
Cells(ThisRow, "E").Value = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'IBM Rational ClearQuest Web'!R2C2:R1048576C10,7,FALSE)"
Cells(ThisRow, "G").Value = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-5],'IBM Rational ClearQuest Web'!R2C2:R1048576C10,9,FALSE)"
Cells(ThisRow, "H").Value = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-6],'IBM Rational ClearQuest Web'!R2C2:R1048576C8,3,FALSE)"

End Sub


Sub DR()
Dim ThisRow As Long
ThisRow = ActiveCell.Row
Cells(ThisRow, "C").ClearContents
Cells(ThisRow, "D").ClearContents
Cells(ThisRow, "E").ClearContents
Cells(ThisRow, "F").ClearContents
Cells(ThisRow, "G").ClearContents
Cells(ThisRow, "H").ClearContents
Cells(ThisRow, "C").Value = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'IBM Rational ClearQuest Web'!R2C12:R1048576C18,2,FALSE)"
Cells(ThisRow, "D").Value = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'IBM Rational ClearQuest Web'!R2C12:R1048576C18,3,FALSE)"
Cells(ThisRow, "E").Value = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'IBM Rational ClearQuest Web'!R2C12:R1048576C18,4,FALSE)"
Cells(ThisRow, "F").Value = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-4],'IBM Rational ClearQuest Web'!R2C12:R1048576C18,5,FALSE)"
Cells(ThisRow, "G").Value = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-5],'IBM Rational ClearQuest Web'!R2C12:R1048576C18,6,FALSE)"
Cells(ThisRow, "H").Value = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-6],'IBM Rational ClearQuest Web'!R2C12:R1048576C18,7,FALSE)"

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't understand the of a macro here? Why not just put the VLOOKUP formula in the cell directly?

Comment: The vlookup is going to be different based on what is selected from the dropdown. The vlookup for CR pulls from different cells that the DR vlookup pulls. And there may be different quantities of CRs or DRs so if I have it already populated in the cell it will pull the wrong data.

Comment: why the loop of one column? Just use the column in the cell and you want FormulaR1C1 not Value: `Cells(.Row, "D").FormulaR1C1 = `

Comment: Just to make sure, `StrComp(Trim(.Value), "DR", vbTextCompare) = 0` will return True if `DR` is **NOT** found in the string

Comment: Even if it's different, you could use INDIRECT to get the right range.

Comment: I had the loop to check if the data in A1:A100 was a CR or DR, to determine which vlookup to do.  I just uploaded an example in the body as well as added more VBA example into the question on the code used when I attempted macros based on the selections.

Comment: I think you are referring to procedures as "macros". Excel macros are procedures but let's call them procedures. Or more specifically subroutines and functions. When you say "sub" that's a subroutine. Breaking your code down in to smaller chunks like this is good. It should work fine that way.

Comment: I may be using it wrong as I am fairly new to this. But the procedures I am referring to as macros were the Sub CR()/Sub Dr(). I had them in a module that would be called when the CR or DR were selected from the dropdown in column A.

Answer (score 0):

Make 2 sheets. One called "CR" and one called "DR". Now, instead of choosing from a dropdown the user will pick the view they want from the sheets. These sheets will have all the VLOOKUPS you need. You can use an IF to handle blanks because you said you may have a variable number of data rows.

For Example:

```
=IF(A1 = "", "", "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'IBM Rational ClearQuest Web'!R2C2:R1048576C8,2,FALSE)")
```

This will only show the VLOOKUP if A1 contains a value. Change that to match whatever check you need to ensure there is data on that line.

Comment: That would work, but we are trying to be able to relate CR's and DR's together.  Having them on one sheet makes it easier to view without having to flip between sheets.

Comment: Aren't you "flipping" views with the dropdown and breaking everything? That sounds much more difficult to me.

Comment: Not really flipping views but more so build a list. I import the CR and DR data, then use that data to build a list of DRs and related CRs per month.

Comment: That would be a 3rd sheet that points to the previous CR and DR sheets. This sounds like relational data that would be much easier to work with in a relational database like Access. Looks like IBM Rational ClearQuest Web has it's own query and reporting engine. You might be making this way harder than it needs to be.

Comment: It is it's own reporting engine.  The CR and DR data is an excel export of a query.  It doesn't relate the data together, and isn't ideal for presenting this information.  What I am essentially trying to do is select DR from the dropdown, enter the DR number and have it pull the DR information.  Then the cells underneath I select CR, and enter the CR number related to it, then repeat for however many CR's are related to it.  So it would look like: 
DR | DR00001 | Submitter | Des. | Etc. | Etc
CR | CR12345 | Submitter | Des. | Etc. | Etc. 
CR | CR11145 | Submitter | Des. | Etc. | Etc.

Comment: ok ok ok, I get it now. That is a relational display model. MSACCESS does this automatically. You will need a boatload of code to rewrite MSACCESS in Excel.

Comment: I am trying not to use MSACCESS because it can pull the relevant data from the vlookup.  I am just trying to find a way so when I type in DR or DR then the number it pulls the relevant information using the vlookup.

Comment: You might want to look in to Pivot Tables and Power Query https://support.office.com/en-us/article/introduction-to-microsoft-power-query-for-excel-6e92e2f4-2079-4e1f-bad5-89f6269cd605

Answer (score 0):

I believe I actually figured it out.  I used this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

On Error GoTo CleanExit:

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then

        Application.EnableEvents = False

        If Target.Value = "CR" Then
            'Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Overdue1"
            Target.Offset(0, 2).Value = "'"
            Target.Offset(0, 3).Value = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'IBM Rational ClearQuest Web'!R2C2:R1048576C8,2,FALSE)"
            Target.Offset(0, 4).Value = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'IBM Rational ClearQuest Web'!R2C2:R1048576C10,7,FALSE)"
            Target.Offset(0, 5).Value = "'"
            Target.Offset(0, 6).Value = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-5],'IBM Rational ClearQuest Web'!R2C2:R1048576C10,9,FALSE)"
            Target.Offset(0, 7).Value = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-6],'IBM Rational ClearQuest Web'!R2C2:R1048576C8,3,FALSE)"
        ElseIf Target.Value = "DR" Then
            'Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Over1"
            Target.Offset(0, 2).Value = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'IBM Rational ClearQuest Web'!R2C12:R1048576C18,2,FALSE)"
            Target.Offset(0, 3).Value = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'IBM Rational ClearQuest Web'!R2C12:R1048576C18,3,FALSE)"
            Target.Offset(0, 4).Value = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'IBM Rational ClearQuest Web'!R2C12:R1048576C18,4,FALSE)"
            Target.Offset(0, 5).Value = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-4],'IBM Rational ClearQuest Web'!R2C12:R1048576C18,5,FALSE)"
            Target.Offset(0, 6).Value = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-5],'IBM Rational ClearQuest Web'!R2C12:R1048576C18,5,FALSE)"
            Target.Offset(0, 7).Value = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-6],'IBM Rational ClearQuest Web'!R2C12:R1048576C18,5,FALSE)"

        End If

        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If

    Exit Sub

CleanExit:
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Err.Clear


End Sub
```

I also think that the tables that I created for the data was causing excel to act weird as well.  When I had the data formatted as a table, all of the rows/columns in the table would update as the macro ran.  However, when they weren't in a table they ran just fine.  I am not sure why but I just ended up not formatting anything as a table.